# Are there any Serious Graph databases not written in Java?

Tags: c++, database, graph, erlang

I am looking for a serious graph database system which is not written in Java.

I am **not** interested in RDF databases, since I expect to be able to store more complex graphs (actually hypergraphs) From within the Java camp, OrientDB is a good example of what I am looking for.

**Disclaimer:** *This is not flamebait. I have nothing against Java, I just want to have an idea of what is out there, implemented in other languages, perhaps as an extension to other dbms, such as MySQL, MongoDb or CouchDb.*

Comment: [Here is a comparison website that might be of some use](http://vschart.com/compare/orientdb/vs/)

Comment: If you have to say *"this is not flamebait"* it is likely that you could have written the question better in the first place. Using "serious" (and capitalized, too!) doesn't help. Instead consider something like *"What mature graph databases are available?"*, tagging it [language-agnostic], and writing in the body that your *"are familiar with several implementation in java but are wonder what alternatives exist"*.

Comment: thanks for the hint. I have followed your suggestions.

Answer (score 6):

Depending on what your requirement is, you could try out [Phoebus](https://github.com/xslogic/phoebus).
It isn't exactly a GraphDB but more of a distributed graph processing framework.

Comment: Phoebus seems really interesting if only not yet mature, I presume.

Comment: aah yes.. i just wrote it as a hobby project.. but ive got a lot of requests from the community to tweak it around..  if you do get time to give a whirr and subsequently find any feature you need added.. kindly let me know.. will try to bake it in

Answer (score 4):

I am now testing the [OQGRaph](http://openquery.com/blog/tag/oqgraph) engine of MySQL. It looks promising but doesn't seem to support multi-graphs.

Comment: MySQL is a RDBMS, not a graph database... I'm so confused by your comment and it's acceptance.

Comment: @AdamMiller MySQL is a DBMS, it has multiple engines for working with databases of different kinds. There was a time when MySQL was just an RDBMS.

Answer (score 3):

[Cayley](https://github.com/google/cayley) is an open-source graph inspired by the graph database behind Google's Knowledge Graph, and it is written in [Go](https://code.google.com/p/go/).

Answer (score 0):

[VTK](http://www.vtk.org) has graph classes. It has a filter to transform graphs to tables, and another to transfer it back. It has SQL connection, too. It could work with [boost](http://www.boost.org), too.

Comment: It is the actual translation of graph to tabular  and back which is a bit cumbersome for large graphs. Also one want to be able to possibly define multiple edge-set based on atributes of a node